# "in the sense in which that concept is relevant" vs. "in the sense that concept is relevant"

Tags: difference

Isn't "**in which**" below redundant? I don't understand what "**in which**" adds to the sentence. If I delete it, what happens to the sentence?

"in which" below hails from English Law Lord Diplock's judgment in *Wheat v Lacon* [1966]. Diplock is referring to the Occupier's Liability Act 1957.

> ### *Wheat v Lacon* [1966]
>
> The defendant brewers were owners of a pub. The
> running of the business was entrusted to a manager,
> who was employed under a service agreement. The
> manager and his wife lived on the first floor of the pub.
> Whilst the claimant and her husband were staying on
> the first floor as paying guests of the manager’s wife,
> the claimant’s husband suffered a fatal fall on his way
> downstairs, caused by a handrail that was too short,
> and insufficient lighting on the stairs. The question for
> the court was whether the defendant brewers were
> liable as occupiers. The House of Lords found that the
> defendant brewers were indeed occupiers of the first
> floor, and owed therefore the common duty of care
> under the 1957 Act (although they were found not to
> have breached that duty on these facts). Significantly,
> the defendant brewers and their manager could both
> be occupiers of the premises simultaneously.
>
> > The title of this Act affords a convenient name-tag
> > for the kind of relationship which does give rise to
> > a duty of care – but it is a name-tag which may be
> > deceptive if it leads one to suppose that the criterion
> > of liability is ‘occupation’ in the sense **in which** that
> > concept is relevant to the law of property or of
> > landlord and tenant or of fiscal, franchise or rating
> > law.<sup>1</sup>
>
> <sup>1</sup> Lord Diplock at 561.

Jodi Garner, *Tort Law* 2021, p 166.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's cited writer has perhaps chosen to use ***in which*** here because he's uneasy about actually repeating the word ***that*** (which repetition is perfectly natural in this exact context). But bear in mind that most native speakers neither notice nor care about such repetition, where the two consecutive instances of a word have different syntactic roles.

The *first* instance of ***[in] that / [in] which*** (as "optionally deletable relativisers") *in the sense **that** that concept is relevant* is no different to, say, *He's the man [**that**] I saw yesterday*. That kind of relativiser is ***always*** optional, even though there are some contexts where it might be considered stylistically poor not to include it.

But the *second* instance (***that** concept*) is ***required*** - it "points to" the *specific* concept being referred to. But we could replace that second ***that*** by ***this*** if we wanted.

---

TL;DR:

> *in the sense **in which that** concept is relevant*
> =
> *in the sense **that this** concept is relevant **in***

...where both highlighted instances of ***in*** could validly be replaced by ***to***.